# Why do I have 2 entries for the same library in yarn.lock

Tags: momentjs, dependency-management, yarnpkg, package.json

To see the main problem, please review a code snippet from yarn.lock:

```
moment@<2.26.0:
  version "2.25.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/moment/-/moment-2.25.3.tgz#252ff41319cf41e47761a1a88cab30edfe9808c0"

"moment@>= 2.9.0", moment@>=2.14.0, moment@^2.10.2, moment@^2.22.2, moment@^2.8.2, moment@^2.9.0:
  version "2.26.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/moment/-/moment-2.26.0.tgz#5e1f82c6bafca6e83e808b30c8705eed0dcbd39a"
```

How did I end up here?

1. deleted `node_modules`
2. edited package.json: replaced `"moment": "2.24.0",` with `"moment": "<2.26.0",`
3. `yarn install`

Now when doing `yarn start` the app doesn't start. I get TS compilation error, which is caused by mixing incompatible versions: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/24377

It looks like a TS dependency hell. How to resolve it? why are there 2 'moment' libraries with different versions?

Answer (score 1):

> How to resolve it?

merge two entries manually

```
moment@<2.26.0, "moment@>= 2.9.0", moment@>=2.14.0, moment@^2.10.2, moment@^2.22.2, moment@^2.8.2, moment@^2.9.0:
  version "2.25.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/moment/-/moment-2.25.3.tgz#252ff41319cf41e47761a1a88cab30edfe9808c0"
```

and run `yarn install`

Comment: I wouldn't do that. It says in capital letters at the top of the file 
`# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.`

Comment: @AsmanUmbetov I don't force you to do so ;) I just shared a solution that worked for me. Maybe in my case yarn.lock file was auto-corrupted after clean `yarn install`, so my app didn't start. So I had to do manual changes that solved this problem (at least temporarily). I agree that it's not a robust fix, because any changes to yarn.lock file may be overwritten by automation.